# How do I change the font in Hexo?

Tags: hexo

I am trying to change the font of my webpage/blog on the Hexo blog framework.

I tried going to head.ejs in themes/landscape/layout/_partial

```
  <% if (config.highlight.enable){ %>
    <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jomolhari" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <% } %>
```

and changing `link href='...family=Source Code Pro'` to `family=...Jomolhari'`,

and I went to _variables.styl in themes/landscape/source/css and changed `font-mono = "Source Code Pro", Consolas, Monaco, Menlo, Consolas, monospace`

to `font-mono='Jomolhari'`

I run 'hexo server' in terminal but my font is still Source Code Pro.

Any ideas?

Thank you!